# receiving some contradicting error messages

Tags: javascript, firebase

So basically I am trying to learn firebase on Javascript, however I came across contradicting error messages.

if I set my experiment.js file to type="module" as so:

```
<script type="module" src="experiment.js"></script>
```

I get this error messages for 3 files: auth, app, firestore (which I assume are coming from the imports from firebase)

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I researched a little and found that I need to set my type to "text/javascript" to solve the issue, however it then gives me this error message:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

In other words, setting my file type to module will bring up errors in other files, whilst setting it to text/javascript solves that problem but creates another one in my file.

I am at a loss as to how to fix this frustrating issue.

If anything is missing from my question, just say so I will edit this question to include it.

Comment: Your server is responding with an incorrect content type. You have to fix it at the server.

Comment: Yeah but whenever I fix one, the other pops up. I have searched for a couple hours before posting and frankly I am completely lost because all I have found is how to solve one or the other, which doesn't eliminate the one I didn't solve. Is there a way to solve both at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer, although I do not think it is the most optimized one.

instead of importing from the file like so:

```
import { x, y, z } from 'firebase/SERVICE';
```

I found out that if you import it like this:

```
import { x, y, z } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-SERVICE.js';
```

the error is solved and the code works like normal.